# Labeling feature class using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, feature-class

I work with ArcGIS Desktop (latest version). I have a feature class called "space" that should be labeled. The label should look like this [room number] + "/ n" + [person] (python). But my problem is not that every room is assigned to a person like a toilet or laboratory. If there is a room that no one owns, the room should only be labled with the room number, but this is not the case. There is no label.

How I tried to do it :

```
def FindLabel ( [room_number],[person] ):
  if [person] ="<Null>":
    return  [person] + '\n' +[Raum_Nummer]
  else:
    return [Raum_Nummer]
```

"< Null >" is my default value

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `if [person] is not ""` or `if [person] != ""` and they should work. Also, under the if/else statements, it should be `[room_number]` not `[Raum_Nummer]`, or at least you need to unify the variables either `[room_number]` or `[Raum_Nummer]`. Do not forget to to check advance labeling to enable carriage return.

Try the following:

```
def FindLabel ([room_number],[person]):
    if [person] is not "":
        return  [person] + '\n' + [room_number]
    else:
        return [room_number]
```

Comment: I tried it but ther is an erro : 
Carriage returns are not allowed in simple expressions

Comment: You need check advance labeling to enable carriage return.